# Codeigniter not adding the Items to Cart

Tags: php, codeigniter, cart

I'm trying to add items to the cart when i tried first time its worked but when i did the update function, the insert function not working, Can Anyone Help? thanks in advance

This is the code

```
public function addCart($id,$qty,$price,$name,$color,$cat)
    {
        $size=$this->input->post('size');
        $data = array(
        'id'      => $id,
        'qty'     => $qty,
        'price'   => $price,
        'name'    => $name,
        'options' => array('Size' => $size, 'Color' => $color)
        );

        $res=$this->cart->insert($data);
        if($res == true){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success',urldecode($name).' Added in Cart.');
        redirect('product/view_all/'.$cat);    
        }
        else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Product Adding Failed :(');
        redirect('product/view_all/'.$cat);
        }

    }

    public function viewCart()
    {
        $data['title']="Products in Cart | DreamShopie.in";
        $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/menu');
        $this->load->view('main_page/cartView',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }

    public function removeCart($id)
    {        
        $data = array(
           'rowid' => $id,
           'qty'   => 0
        );

    $this->cart->update($data);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Item Removed');
    redirect('cart/viewCart');
    }
```

Comment: <?php echo form_open('cart/addCart/'.$product['product_id'].'/1/'.$tot.'/'.$product['p_name'].'/'.$product['color'].'/'.$product['category']); ?>

Comment: This is the function called

Comment: show your model function of update()

Comment: It's the library function

Comment: Show your `insert()` and `update()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $this->cart is your db , didnt you miss db name?

```
 $this->cart->insert('db_name', $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`insert()` and `update()` function in the `cart` model should be like this

```
public function insert($data){
    return $this->db->insert('table', $data);
}

public function update($data){
    $this->db->where('column', $value);
    $this->db->set($data);
    return $this->db->update('table');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I own find the answer , the errorr occurred because the name contains illegal characters from the URL , so I use urldecode function for name

Problem solved.